# MongoDB Compass display fields in doc by order

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

Looking for a way to view the results of a query where the displayed fields **in the doc** are ordered (lexicographically in my case).

Example:

I'm getting back from a query one document, which is what I need. This document has 30 fields and I'm looking to see the value in one of them. My issue is that the order of the fields is, well, kinda random. Not sorted in any way I'm aware of.

Comment: I **think** that the indexes are displayed first, which I get. But the rest aren't so much. Some are ordered, but some not.

Comment: This might help you a little.  https://codeshack.io/json-sorter/

Comment: I use NoSQLBooster that can be sort key name in Tree/Table View